# Android Admob not refresh ads - repeat same ad

Tags: android, admob

I spent 2 days analysing why my program serve all the time same banner.
Admob returns same banner most of the time. It change it 3-4 times in day and again repeat banner hundred times.
After lot of experiments with Admob site options - I made second program with same publisher ID inside. And everyting is fine! Same code for requesting ads. Same publisher Id. The only difference is package name.

It is not good idea to change package name because of this problem. But I can serve 4-5 different banners dayly :(
Does anybody have the same problem?

Comment: I want to show ad continue.. how can you do that ??can you please share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I stop internet - my ads continue to show on screen. sdk repeats last banners cached somewhere in device. On 20-30 ad request I receive once: 'No ads to serve for you' or some like this. So Admob repeat last banners when there is no connection or no new ads from google.
False alarm and spent 2 days to fight nonexistent problem.